# Can not assign value to data frame item

Tags: python, pandas

Hopefully there is someone who can help me with this 6 hours ongoing headache. I am trying to use Pandas to pair the rows in a purchase history with the rows in a sales history.

There is a one to many relationship between the incoming products we recieve to the warehouse, and the sales orders the goods is dispatched out on. In pandas I iterate through the sales rows, finding the purchase row it belongs too, then assigning a purchase line identifier to the sales row.

The 6 hour headache is a simple case of assigning a new value to a dataframe item (I think that is the correct chargon, cell would be the corresponding term used in excel). I have read about the difference between calling a copy and a view, and I am 99,99999% sure that it is not the problem.

After using over a 1000 trials (ipython counts the prompts), and the print command, I have narrowed the problem of my malfunctioning code down to this line, which, no matter how I write it, does not work as intended

```
InnkjopHisto.ix[InnkjoptAntall.index.values[0], ['Rest']] = np.float64(0)
```

the line is a part of the code below, in case that is of interest. I have tried witing the line in a range of different ways to no avail. I can not, for the life of me assign a value to the item. Other failed tries:

```
InnkjopHisto['Rest'][InnkjoptAntall.index.values[0] = np.float64(0)
InnkjopHisto.loc[InnkjoptAntall.index.values[0], ['Rest']] = np.float64(0)
```

I have also tried assigning all kinds of object types, to see if that was the problem, but it does not seem to be. Thank you for looking at my problem

```
for salgslinje in SalgsHisto.iterrows():    
    if (salgslinje[0] == 599):
        referanseIDer = DFAllok[(DFAllok['OrderCopyNo'] == salgslinje[1]['OrderNo']) & (DFAllok['ArticleNo'] == salgslinje[1]['ArticleNo'])&(DFAllok['Brukt'] == 'ikke')]['ReferenceID']
        if len(referanseIDer) > 0:
             for Alloknummer in referanseIDer.iteritems():
                InnkjoptAntall = InnkjopHisto[InnkjopHisto['Rest'] > 0]
                InnkjoptAntall = InnkjoptAntall[(InnkjoptAntall['OrderNo'] == Alloknummer[1])&(InnkjoptAntall['ArticleNo'] == salgslinje[1]['ArticleNo'])]['Rest']
                if len(InnkjoptAntall) > 0 :
                    differanse = InnkjoptAntall.values[0] + salgslinje[1]['Quantity']
                    if differanse == np.float64(0):
                        InnkjopHisto.ix[InnkjoptAntall.index.values[0], ['Rest']] = np.float64(0)
                        DFAllok.ix[Alloknummer[0], ['Brukt']] = 'Brukt'
                        SalgsHisto['KorresponderendeInnkjop'][salgslinje[0]] = InnkjopHisto.ix[InnkjoptAntall.index.values[0], 'UnikID']
                break
```

EDIT: Answering Jeff's comment, here is some further info:

```
InnkjopHisto.head()

     SubGroupNo  OrderNo    ArticleNo   Created         Quantity      UnikID      Rest
0    0               801606         101575   2011-09-27 08:10:12     1260    0   1260
1    100102          800157         100113   2011-04-04 13:55:13     2040    1   2040
2    100102          800158         101124   2011-04-04 13:20:01     1330    2   1330
3    100102          800170         100124   2011-04-04 08:38:50     1065    3   1065
4    100102          800216         101124   2011-04-07 13:22:18     1129    4   1129


InnkjopHisto.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5758 entries, 0 to 5763
Data columns (total 7 columns):
SubGroupNo    5758  non-null values
OrderNo       5758  non-null values
ArticleNo     5758  non-null values
Created       5758  non-null values
Quantity      5758  non-null values
UnikID        5758  non-null values
Rest          5758  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), int64(4), object(1)


pd.__version__
'0.11.0'
```

Comment: this looks ok, can you put up ``df.head()``, and ``df.info()``; fyi you dont' need ``np.float(0)``, just ``0`` will work. what version pandas?

Comment: @Jeff thak you for looking at this. I have added all the info you asked for in the question above. PS the np.float(0) was one of my many far fetched and desperate attempts to get the code working.

Comment: @Jeff; your question about the version, made me check whether 0.11.0 was the current version, and it was not. 0.12.0 was released two weeks ago. I installed 0.12.0, and the code is now working. Thank you for your help! I was probably weeks from thinking along those lines

Comment: gr8. as an aside, your inner loop look vectorizable (as opposed to iterating over ``referenaceIDer``). Create the mask (which is essentially your conditions where you want to assign; create the result and assign), e.g. ``df.loc[mask,columns_i_want] = result_df``, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)